# can't get header subject using POPFetchHeaderOperation

Tags: java, android, header, mailcore2, mailcore

I used POPFetchHeaderOperation to get header of a email when developing a email application on andriod. I can't get the subject of the header if the email is sent with a PC. I will get the subject when the email is sent with a phone. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I'm using mailcore2 framework

Comment: Looks like this:  final POPFetchHeaderOperation popFetchHeaderOperation = mPOPSession.fetchHeaderOperation(popMessageInfo.index());
popFetchHeaderOperation.start(new OperationCallback() {
@Override
public void succeeded() {
EmailBean bean = new EmailBean();
MessageHeader header = popFetchHeaderOperation.header();
bean.setFrom(header.from().mailbox());
bean.setTo(header.to().get(index).mailbox());
List<Address> ccAddresses = header.cc();
bean.setSubject(header.subject());}